# Ship Python interpreter (interactive mode enabled) with an application

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

(Before marking as duplicate make sure you understand what this question is about)

I have an application that has a Python API, and I want to ship the Python interpreter which would enable users to run Python in **interactive mode**. The shipped Python will contain my package pre-installed.

The application is written in Java, but I did not want to couple the shipped Python and the application if possible - I wanted to have a **self-contained** binary that allows running Python in interactive mode and then having my application referencing it. Bottom line is I wanted a way to ship Python itself in a self-contained way, that is a good way to phrase it.

Just to further clarify - the purpose is *not* to ship a binary with a compiled Python script using something like pyinstaller or freezing tools, as I have found on many duplicate threads such as [Shipping interpreter with Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752218/shipping-interpreter-with-python-application), [Embed Python interpreter in a Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441172/embed-python-interpreter-in-a-python-application), [How to bundle a Python application including dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106725/how-to-bundle-a-python-application-including-dependencies) and others. The user being able to use Python in interactive mode is a hard requirement.

So, again, the whole point here is being able to run the shipped Python **in interactive mode** with some pre-installed dependencies, in which case I think the solutions I have found so far (some of them referenced above) are not robust/self-contained enough. Let me know if I am missing something, which might be the case.

Comment: What language is your application written in?

Comment: Java, but I did not want to couple the solution to the application's language if possible, instead I wanted to have this binary that allows to run Python in interactive mode and reference it inside the application (Thanks for the question, I'll update my description on it)

Comment: If any of those options you link to for bundling applications include an interpreter executable somewhere in the distributed folder, then you could use that. I haven't tried, and it's from 2014 with no recent update, but [bbfreeze](https://pypi.org/project/bbfreeze/) does include an executable for the Python interpreter itself. Maybe pyinstaller does that too? Not clear from their docs but I would try it. py2exe does not as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks, @Stuart, that's a good lead. I will try it and let you know.